# My code deletes last item in list and not the item i want

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter

I want to create a function where the user gets a list of users from the database and can choose to delete on of them from the database. It looks the way i want, i get all items in rows with a delete button for each and they are named correct. But the function doesnt seem to work the way i want. If i click any delete button the last user gets deleted. Im new to this so im sure i made a mistake but i dont know where.

```
def delete():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("DELETE FROM databasetable WHERE oid = " + str(i[5]))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM databasetable")
listfromdatabase = c.fetchall()
conn.commit()
conn.close()

for i in listfromdatabase:
    label = Label(frameskidlararenamn, text=i[0])
    label.pack()
    button = Button(frameskidlarareknapp, text="Delete " + str(i[0]), command=delete)
    button.pack()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `"SELECT *, oid FROM databasetable"` --> `"SELECT * FROM databasetable"`

Comment: Im not sure i understand. If i write "SELECT * FROM databasetable" it doesnt return the oid, only the inputs i created.

Comment: `*` --> All fields of the table

Comment: Are you really sure that this is the way it works in sqlite? Because the oid doesnt get returned if i write * but it gets returned correctly the way i wrote it. I dont think thats the problem. If i print the list to the terminal everything looks correct.

Comment: Im using sqlite3.

Comment: Yes - I am sure about `*`

Comment: When i deleted ", oid" i get this error:

IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: This is a bug in you code..

Comment: I found the video where i learned this, check 16:38 in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AK1J8xF4fuk&t=757s

Comment: Im thinking that the problem is that when you press the button you are not in the for loop anymore and therefore my code doesnt know which user i want to delete. But i dont know how to solve it.

Comment: add `print()` across the code and see what is going on

Comment: you have `"DELETE FROM databasetable WHERE oid = " + str(i[5])` in `delete()`, how does it know what `i[5]` is it?

Comment: see if there a way to pass arguments like `command=delete(i[0])`, then you can `def delete(item): ..... DELETE FROM databasetable WHERE oid = " + item`

Comment: If i print(str(i[5])) (the oid of each user) in the buttom of the for loop it returns 1, 2, 3 which is correct since i have 3 users atm. If i print(str(i[5])) in the end of the function it doesnt print anything. Thats why i think the problem is what i wrote above.

Comment: Thank you sittsering! I will try that!

Comment: because scope of `i` should be within that for loop

Comment: When i tried this i get
    sqlite3.OperationalError: near "E": syntax error

Comment: Maybe my code is wrong from the beginning so if anyone has any idea how to do what i want with some other code i would appreciate

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the loop `for i in listfromdatabase:` `i` is the last item.
So the delete function delete this last item.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of delete is set to target the fifth element of i

```py
def delete():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("DELETE FROM databasetable WHERE oid = " + str(i[5]))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

You should instead pass in the oid to delete by changing the definition

```py
def delete(oid):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("DELETE FROM databasetable WHERE oid = " + str(oid))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: When i tried this i get this error:
    sqlite3.OperationalError: near "E": syntax error

Comment: Have you changed the definition of the button as well? it has to pass the correct parameter to the command, something like command=delete(i[0]) or on whichever index your oid is stored on should do the trick

Comment: No i had not. I changed it now and this caused a new problem and i have no idea why. Now all the users get deleted without me doing anything. If i add a new user and open the window again, only the new user is there. If i close the window and open it again no users are there. When i print the list to the terminal before the for loop the list is empty.

Comment: Try making the command lambda, so you define it as command=lambda: delete(i[5]). There's a chance it's firing on load unintenionally

Comment: See my answer to sittsering who suggested this after your comment. I tried it and i got rid of the error but the original problem came back. All delete-buttons delete the last item.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works, passing an argument to command with lambda Function.
changed `lambda : delete(i[5])` to `lambda item=i[5]: delete(item)`

```
button1 = [None for _ in range(len(listfromdatabase))]
for n,i in enumerate(listfromdatabase):
    label = Label(frameskidlararenamn, text=i[0])
    label.pack()
    button1[n] = Button(frameskidlarareknapp, text="Delete " + str(i[0]),command=lambda item=i[5]: delete(item))
    button1[n].pack()
```

```
def delete(item):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("DELETE FROM databasetable WHERE oid = " + str(item))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Just to be sure, check with two buttons with same name but different function. like

```
def printnum(num):
    #print num on a label or something
button = Button(frameskidlarareknapp, text="print num 1", command=lambda: printnum(1))
button.pack()
button = Button(frameskidlarareknapp, text="print num 2", command=lambda: printnum(2))
button.pack()
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I tried this and i no longer have the problem i got when i tried what Max Strandberg wrote. But the original problem came back. When i press any delete button the last item in the list gets deleted.

Comment: I saw that i wrote my original post a bit incorrect. Its not only the first delete-button that works. Every delete-button works but all of them delete the last item.

Comment: i feel like it may have to do with button being same name, maybe different button name is needed. Updated 3 lines

Comment: Yes that sounds logical. Do you have any idea how i should write my code to give them individual name depending on how many users there is in the database?

Comment: Sorry didnt see your updated code, will try.

Comment: Sorry, It didnt work. It stills delete the last item.

Comment: I tried the code you added with two buttons with the same name. It works, if i press button 1 it prints 1 and button 2 prints 2. So it seems to work.

Comment: @alexander just updated, try one more. this is last one, hope it works

Comment: WOW! It worked! Thank you so much! If you ever visit Sweden, tell me and i will buy you a beer!

Comment: @alexander  great, will do